# Getting wrong DVD chapter times from lsdvd, Mplayer and Handbrake: the reported chapter boundaries delay progressively compared to the real ones

Tags: dvd

I'm trying to split video from DVDs into chapters. `lsdvd`, `mplayer -identify` and Handbrake all report the same chapter times, but these times cut into following *actual* chapters (episodes), progressively more so towards the end of a disc. I've checked these times by hand in VLC, and they're indeed wrong, just as cutting with `ffmpeg` shows. Three discs from one collection exhibit this issue so far (haven't yet tried on unrelated DVDs).

Meanwhile, VLC jumps to the proper boundary times from the DVD menus, so presumably it has the right info.

Why could this be happening? Is there a way to obtain proper chapter times? I'd prefer to keep the process sorta-automated and avoid noting the times manually, for reasons of both purity and practicality. And to know the root cause and a solution for the future.